# Convert CPP Code in .exe in MS Visual Studio 2010 by VC++ Projec

Tags: visual-c++

I have the source code of a .CPP program and I want to generate an .EXE file of this project, for that I create a new **EMPTY PROJECT(VC++)** in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and add all the .cpp and .h files into the Source File folder.

Now when I build the solution I get the error:

```
Error : Failed to locate: **"CL.exe".** The system cannot find the file specified.
```

In my system CL.exe file is in this path: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\CL.exe`

Some answers state that it should be at this location: `C:/Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ce\bin`

So can you please suggest what should I do to solve this error?

Or can you give any other solution which can generate an .EXE file of a CPP program?

I want to integrate/Debug this project in Microsoft Visual studio 2010 (VC++)

Link of Source Code : http://code-industry.net/downloads.php

Right click on this to download source (Download ImagePrinter Free Source code (zip archive)
)

I am trying hard to debug this code but still don't get any solution for this.

Any help is Appriciated

Comment: This is a rather basic "it no worky" kind of problem.  Don't attempt this until you can get your machine stable enough to get "Hello world" building and running.

Comment: Let the VS2010 wizard generate a similar project and compile it w/o any code change. If it does not compile you might consider re-installing VS2010.

Comment: I have tried with simple program but t gives error like this 
"Error 1 error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt C:\Users\2024\Downloads\TestProject\LINK project".

Comment: The "conversion to COFF" is a known problem. Download and install [a service pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)

Comment: Any more solution , even i also looking for same kind of solution, any help would be grateful. Even some alternative code / reference links for the similar will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.